# Do you recognise this bike brand?

Tags: mountain-bike

I've bought this MTB second-hand a couple of years ago, the vendor told me the brand, but I can't remember. Does someone recognise this logo?
I haven't found any swiss bike brand starting with "p" with this logo.

[image: swiss made by whom?]

Comment: A photo of the whole bike, from the right hand side might be useful too.

Comment: I've added this to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_Bicycles   What licence is your head tube badge published under ?  I'd like to include that on the wikipedia page, with your permission.

Comment: Thanks @Criggie ! 
I've not set anything particular for the picture, but feel free to use it :) 
(I'll see if I can set a licence)

Comment: Wikipedia were their typical gate-keeping selves and have deleted that page already   So https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bicycle_brands_and_manufacturing_companies is left incomplete and useless for your purposes, which is a shame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some googling suggests there's a brand called **Price** which claims to be "swiss-made"

<sup>from https://bikeswitzerland.com/our-new-swiss-made-touring-bikes/</sup>

which lead me to finding this head tube badge image

[image: Screenshot from a flash 360 degree view of the Price gravel bike.]

**Their website is at http://www.price-bikes.ch/ and is bilingual**